# How to change the /contact router to something else?

Tags: magento2, xml

By default Magento2 offers a contact form. This can be reached under `http://domain.tld/mage2orwhatever/contact`.

But we want to have the router to be translated, in our case it'd be `kontakt`.

How can I change the router from `contact` to `kontakt` or something different?